# SQL Server last called stored procedures with parameters

Tags: sql-server, stored-procedures, tracking

I am using ASP.NET environment.

Is it possible to track last N number of stored procedures called with parameters info?

I see in this article "Recently executed stored procedures";

http://sqlfool.com/2009/08/find-recently-executed-stored-procedures/

But I need input parameters also.

If not what can be the best way to track it?

For example, adding an insert statement to a information table for every single procedure beginning?

Or is there any better solution for this?

Comment: What about calls that aren't stored procedures?

Comment: I do not use any other calls other than stored procedures.

Comment: Nope. I do not need triggers, I just use SP & Transactions in my database structure. That's why it would be great for me to track which stored procedure is called with what parameters.

Comment: If you funnel all your stored procedure calls through a central method, you can do whatever kind of logging you want from there.

Comment: thanks for the info, i am also thinking to set my environment up this way. thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Yes i think it is only way too add the insert statement and log parameter in every stored procedure.